# Stack 8MiB, then why this code "almost" works?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, heap-memory, stack-memory

I read everywhere.
The **stack** has **8MB**, that's why you should use pointer, to store stuff in the **heap**.

Well, on my machine the code bellow works with 11MB of char, but not with 12MB.
Is my `char c[Nc]` **array** storage in the so called **heap**?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int Nc = 1024*1024;  // megabyte

    Nc = Nc * 11;  // works
    //Nc = Nc * 12;  // Segmentation fault (core dumped)

    char c[Nc];

    c[0] = 'A';
    c[Nc-1] = 'Z';

    printf("%dmb\n", Nc/1024/1024);

    printf("%c-%c\n", c[0], c[Nc-1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Any explanations?
I am just "user" not a programmer.

Comment: And the premise "I read every where.
The stack only have 8mb" is simply not true. This can only be true for a very specific configuration.

Comment: This means that on machine C has 11GB stack?

Comment: You have been already pointed to the fact your calculation is wrong.

Comment: @EugeneSh.yes. megabytes. So I have 11mb for the stack?

Comment: Overflowing the stack is *undefined behavior*, so the fact it is not crashing for you doesn't mean it is not overflowed.

Comment: (a) The default stack size is 8 MiB on some systems and different on others. You did not tell us what system you are using, so we cannot know what the size is on your system. It might be 12 MiB. (b) The default stack size is changeable. (c) A compiler might observe that your program does not use all of the array and optimize your program so that it does not actually create the array at all. You did not tell us what compiler or compilation switches you are using, so we do not know what the compiler did with your program.

Comment: (d) It might be possible to overflow the stack **so far** that your program goes into a different section of memory that is mapped for other reasons, so that `c[Nc-1] = 'Z';` is actually writing into, and damaging, other data in your program.

Comment: gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)  
kernel 2.6.32-696.1.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: *The stack has 8MB*

Don't trust everything you read "everywhere". 

*Is my char c[Nc] array storage in the so called heap*

No it is not.

Comment: Your answer is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239323/100620
Try growing ulimit with something like `ulimit -s 16000`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Where does the standard say that? I don't think the standard dictates that a stack is even required. I also don't think tossing around the term *undefined behavior* is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are compiling your program with at least some optimizations. When I compile your code, on GCC or Clang, with anything other than `-O0` the compiler optimizes away the creation of the `char` array. ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/geF9w7))

If you compile your program with `-fsanitize=undefined` it will catch this as undefined behavior.

Putting such a large array on the stack is generally considered bad practice. Large objects should be statically allocated or allocated on the heap. The operating system sets its default stack allocation to a level where most programs will not need to worry about it, it is not a guarantee. It is your responsibility as a programmer to make sure that your program has enough stack space to run. If you need to get or check the amount of stack space, you can use `getrlimit()` and `setrlimit()`. See `man getrlimit` for more information.

Comment: The array in your gobolt link just optimized out because values are known in advance. No memory access needed. No reason to crash. Just add `extern int n`  and `c[Nc - 1-n] = 'Z';` and you will see it: https://godbolt.org/z/LoV27m